# Choose option in select box by clicking URL

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Sorry about the vague title - the behavior I'm trying to get is a little difficult to summarize.

I am updating our company's website, and the first thing we changed was to create a contact form, versus having all of the company email addresses exposed via a mailto: link.

The contact form is fairly straightforward...name, sender's email address, message...and then a selectbox where they can choose who to email.

Now, on other pages, we still have a few mailto: links for specific activities.  The next thing I'd like to do is change these links to point to the contact page.

What I would like to do is figure out some way to have the URL to the contact page pass a variable for the "who to email" select so that it auto-populates with the right selection.

I.E. - if they click on a link for a job advertisement, it populates with the human resources person.  If they want to know HIPPA stuff, it populates the select with the person in charge of HIPPA.  Etc.

The current contact page utilizes PHP, so I was thinking maybe an interpreter could be set up to read a value from the URL.

EDIT:

So this is the selectbox I'm using (shortened and with names modified).  All I'm trying to accomplish is if you click on a link from, say, default.htm for operations information - it shoots you to contact.php, and selects "wayne" from the sendto list:

```
<select id="sendTo" name="sendTo">
    <option id="jim" value="jim">Jim, Executive Vice President</option>
    <option id="wayne" value="wayne">Wayne, Vice President, Chief Operating Officer</option>
    <option id="chris" value="chris">Chris, Operations Director</option>
    <option id="val" value="val">Val, Communications Center Director</option>
    <option id="kathy" value="kathy">Kathy, Client Accounts Director</option>

</select>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with programming in Java? Why the Java tag?

Comment: Because I saw a few articles that discussed similar techniques that used jscript or JSON?

Comment: If you need to read or set form elements and URL parameters with PHP, many questions on this site cover that topic. If you have another, specific question about your code, please modify your post to show your code and to provide specific details about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @user2405805 you are thinking of `javascript`. Not the same as `Java`. I updated the tag for you

Comment: The classic comic: http://www.flickr.com/photos/schrader/3779250024/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
<input type="checkbox" value="steve" <?php echo $_GET[ 'email' ] == 'steve' ? 'checked="checked"' : ''?> />Steve
```

This will make a checkbox, and if the `$_GET` variable `email` is set to `steve`, this checkbox will be checked

and for a select

```
<select>
    <option value="steve" <?php echo $_GET['email'] == 'steve' ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Steve</option>
</select>
```

for your URL, (notice above i changed variables), you would have something like

`http://www.example.com/contact.php?email=steve`

Comment: I'm sorry...but I'd like to avoid using a checkbox...we have 12 contacts currently, and it's likely that more could be added.  The current method uses a select that passes a sendto value to a secondary php page for mailing.

Comment: But they're using a "selectbox" (dropdown)...

Comment: Fixed in an edit, idk where i read checkbox haha

Comment: You should be able to take what ive done with the select, and do something similar for your select

Comment: I will give it a shot.  So then from the URL side, what would I use?  somesite.com/contact.php?.....?

Comment: Edited the post again

Comment: Worked like a charm!  One slight modification to the select code is there's an extra ">".  

So this:

'<option value="steve" <?=$_GET['email'] == 'steve' ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Steve</option>'

Should be this:

'<option value="steve" <?=$_GET['email'] == 'steve' ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>Steve</option>'

Comment: No, no it shouldnt! The first `>` is part of the end php tag, the second `>` is part of the `option` tag

Comment: I implemented it and the selectbox has ">steve" in the field, instead of just "steve".  Is this maybe just chrome?

Comment: Ahh, it looks like you dont have short tags enabled. H/o editing the post

Comment: Changed the `<?=`'s to `<?php echo `

Comment: My 2 cents : Be carefull about JS injection, people can share link to your website and inject JS in ?email=... part of your URL.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the $_GET array to pass data to your contact page then put

```
<option value="bob" <?=($_GET['person']=='bob')?'selected="selected"':''?> >bob</option>
```

Comment: this isnt cross browser compatible